# c# StringReader, XmlReader, XSLT - Unexpected XML Declaration

Tags: c#, xslt, xmlreader, stringreader

I've been using this function to read XML from a string and apply an XSLT style sheets, it has been working very well for small portions of XML:

```
private static string TransformXML(String XML, String XSLT)
{
   string output = String.Empty;
    using (StringReader srt = new StringReader(XSLT)) 
    { 
        using (StringReader sri = new StringReader(XML)) 
        {
            using (XmlReader xrt = XmlReader.Create(srt))
            using (XmlReader xri = XmlReader.Create(sri))
            {
                XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
                xslt.Load(xrt);
                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                using (XmlWriter xwo = XmlWriter.Create(sw, xslt.OutputSettings)) // use OutputSettings of xsl, so it can be output as HTML
                {
                    xslt.Transform(xri, xwo);
                    output = sw.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return output; 
}
```

However, with large portions of XML, I'm getting errors, even though I know it is correctly formatted.

Here is an example error: Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 1, position 30001.

I'm guessing there is a limit on the buffering, but I can't quite work it out - the code is within an SSIS package and different script tasks produce and translate the XML.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: How large approximately? You Create some big strings, there is a 2GB limit (1 GB ASCII/UTF8) a piece.

Comment: No where near 2GB, around 60k or more lines of UTF8 at around 60kb. It feels like the code isn't reading the whole of the XML document

Comment: Well the error in the post title "Unexpected XML Declaration" suggests there is an XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0"?>` in the middle of the markup. This can happen if someone tried to embed one XML document in another. The XML declaration is only allowed at the very beginning of an XML document.

Comment: Apologies - that is the error I was getting before I made the post (it was quite late), I now get an Unexpected EOF at position in Line 1, position 300001 - consistently